# Is caching the correct class to use for storing data received?

Tags: c#, caching

I am trying to find the best way to store data received from a socket server I created.  I then also need to wait for a client to open the connection to the server and request the data (which will be objects consisting of trade information).  After the data is requested the server then forwards a copy to the client in a CSV format.

So I believe I know how to do all of the above but not sure how to cache the data, or if it is wise to use it because of its volatility.  I have never used the cache class before and before I dig into it I was curious if I am going in the right direction (in using the cache class)?

If this is not the right direction then please kindly suggest an alternative.

Comment: have you tried a google search on `Caching a network Stream` perhaps ..?

Comment: Looks like I may not even have to use a cache.  It appears I could avoid learning this and just use a list instead, I was taking my bosses directions to literally when he said to use a cache.